# Code coverage error for class

Tags: unit-test, class, code-coverage

I do have a class that have actions for creating the url argument values to be created. This variables is passed to VF page for redirection to a page. But it's showing a code coverage issue. How can I create a test class for this class. Below is the code.

```
    public class SampleRequestButtonLogic {

    public string returnURL     {get;set;}
    public string OptyId        {get;set;}
    public string OptyName      {get;set;}
    public string OptyRegion    {get;set;}
    public string OptySTer      {get;set;}
    public string OptyTerr      {get;set;}
    public string OptyAccnt     {get;set;} 
    public string OptyAccntId   {get;set;} 


    public SampleRequestButtonLogic (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        returnURL = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('retURL');
        OptyId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        Opportunity oppValuesStore = [Select name, Design_Region__c, Design_Super_Territory__c,Design_Territory__c, AccountId FROM Opportunity where id=: OptyId]; 

        OptyAccntId = oppValuesStore.AccountId;
        Account oppAccount = [Select Name FROM Account where id=: oppValuesStore.AccountId]; 

        try{
            if(oppValuesStore.name != null){
                OptyName    = oppValuesStore.name;
            }
            if(oppValuesStore.Design_Region__c != null){
                OptyRegion  = oppValuesStore.Design_Region__c;
            }
            if(oppValuesStore.Design_Super_Territory__c != null){
                OptySTer    = oppValuesStore.Design_Super_Territory__c;
            }
            if(oppValuesStore.Design_Territory__c != null){
                OptyTerr    = oppValuesStore.Design_Territory__c;
            }
            if(oppAccount.name != null){
                OptyAccnt   = oppAccount.name;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the test class I have used so far

```
    @isTest
private class Test_OptySampleRequestButtonLogic {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

        User u= [select id, isactive from User where isActive=True limit 1];

        Account a=new Account(Name='Test Account', FAE__c=u.id);
        insert a;
        system.assertNotEquals(a.id,null);

        Opportunity op=new Opportunity(Name='Test Parts Opp',Anticipated_Production_Date__c = system.today() + 10, CLoseDate=system.today(),StageName='Qualified',AccountId=a.id,Program_EAU__c='000');
        insert op;     
        system.assertNotEquals(op.id,null);

        Product2 p=new Product2(Name='Test EVB Product',IsActive=true,Business_Unit__c='Power',Item_class__c='PPE',Item_number__c='12387',Product_Status_Code1__c='40|Prod.Rel. Unrestrict.U');
        insert p;

        Part__c pt = new Part__c(Product__c=p.id,Stage__c='Lead',ASP__c='11',Part_Probability__c=10,Opportunity__c=op.id);
        insert pt;
        system.assertNotEquals(p.id,null);

        User usr=[select id ,name from User where name = 'api_integration'];
        system.assertNotEquals(usr.id,null);

        Part__c part1=new Part__c(Opportunity__c = op.id,Product__c = p.id/*Anticipated_Production_Date__c = system.today(),*/);
        insert part1;
        system.assertNotEquals(part1.id,null);

        ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('id',part1.id);  
        system.assertNotEquals('id',null);      

        ApexPages.StandardController controller= new ApexPages.StandardController (part1);

        OptySampleRequestButtonLogic OptySampleRequestButtonLogic1= new OptySampleRequestButtonLogic(controller);


    }

}
```

Comment: What did you already tried? What is the error that you are facing?

Comment: @m Peixoto, I updated my question with the test class that I have already written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have some pretty bad practices in this code that I strongly recommend removing before you go any further.

- Get rid of the `try/catch` block. You should never have an empty
  `catch` block or a `catch` block that does nothing but
  `System.debug()`. All that does is make debugging and testing more
  difficult and run the risk of introducing bad behavior into your
  production database, because you never see errors that occur. `try/catch` is for *handling* errors, not *hiding* them.
- Delete all of your `assert` statements about Ids. They do not show anything about the behavior of your code. If something goes wrong during an
  `insert` operation, you will get an exception that you can
  troubleshoot. There's no need to assert that an `Id` is not null
  after an insert. `assert` statements are for showing that your code
  behaves the way you expect it to behave.

One of the major reasons you have limited code coverage here is that your test code is not populating the fields on the Opportunity that your controller is looking for. This means that the bodies of your `if` statements are not executed in test context and hence aren't covered.

You need to ensure that your test class's data is structured so that each possible code path gets exercised, and then show (using `assert` statements) that the behavior is what is expected after each test. In this case, you should be asserting that the values of your instance variables are equal to the values you populate in your test Opportunity and Account.